# Create an mp4 video from list of frames using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an directory with images that looks like this:

```
frame0d.jpg
frame1d.jpg
frame2d.jpg
...
frame4297d.jpg
```

I need to create mp4 file with 30 fps from them.

I've tried command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i frame%04d.jpg video.mp4
```

But it fails with error:

```
[image2 @ 0000026fd7c5a000] Could find no file with path 'frame%04d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
frame%04d.jpg: No such file or directory
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are your files actually named `frame<number>d.jpg`? or are they `frame<number>.jpg`?   This question suggests what you are trying is possible: https://superuser.com/questions/249101/how-can-i-combine-30-000-images-into-a-timelapse-movie

Comment: frames named "frame<number>d.jpg , with the 'd'.Exactly as in example: frame0d.jpg. BDW - windows OS in my case

Comment: Solved :)  problem was the 'd' ... Needed to specify it twice , like this: ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i frame%01dd.jpg video.mp4

Comment: I thought as much.  The format definition `%04d` means look for up to 4 numbers i in the filename.  As you have a trailing d after the number then that needs to be specified explicitly.  If your files didn't have the extra d after the frame number (or had a different letter), you would have spotted this straight away.

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i frame%01dd.jpg video.mp4